# link_to problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to Rails and I'm I am trying to create a basic blog application, but I'm having trouble linking.

I have three controllers (authors, pages and static_pages). They all work fine but I'm trying to link to two pages in `static_pages`. They are `about.html.erb` and `help.html.erb`. I'm using a partial to create a navigation menu at the top.

I'm getting the following error:

```
ActionController::RoutingError in Pages#index

No route matches {:controller=>"pages", :action=>"about"}

1: <%= link_to 'Homepage', pages_path %> |
2: <%= link_to 'List of Authors', authors_path %> |
3: <%= link_to 'About', :action => 'about' %> |
4: <%= link_to 'Help', :action => 'help' %>
```

The code in my menu partial is:

```
<%= link_to 'Homepage', pages_path %> |
<%= link_to 'List of Authors', authors_path %> |
<%= link_to 'About', :action => 'about' %> |
<%= link_to 'Help', :action => 'help' %>
```

My static_pages controller looks like this:

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  def About
  end

  def Help
  end
end
```

I understand that it's probably something very simple but as I say I'm new to Rails and web development in general so any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: Method name convention is names like `about`, `some_thing` instead of `About`,`Some_Thing`, `SomeThing` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked your routes using rake routes in your terminal/console? If not this is a good way to solve problems related to route errors.

Comment: I was just coming back to say I'd sorted it. I checked routes.rb and I had used capital letters again! That keeps tripping me up.

Answer (score 3):

Trivial, make your action methods lowercase. Ruby is case sensitive with variable and method names.

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController

  def about 
  end

  def help 
  end

end
```

Comment: I've tried that and I'm still getting the same error. It is probably something really simple!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your link_to methods are trying to access the StaticPagesController, your error seems to indicate that Rails is trying to create the URL for the about action through PagesController.

Check the docs for [ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html), especially the link_to and url_for methods.

Comment: I've changed the menu partial to: <%= link_to 'Homepage', pages_path %> |
<%= link_to 'List of Authors', authors_path %> |
<%= link_to 'About', :controller =>'Static_Pages' :action => 'about' %> |
<%= link_to 'Help', :controller =>'Static_Pages' :action => 'help' %>